WPF OnPreviewTouchDown and OnPreviewMouseDown strange behavior opening new Window
I found some strange behavior in this scenario.
Simple WPF project with a TextBox with two events PreviewTouchDown and PreviewMouseDown
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="800"
        Width="1000">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
                 PreviewTouchDown="TextBox_PreviewTouchDown"
                 PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseDown" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

in code behind open second window in the touch event.
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}

private void TextBox_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 w = new Window1();
    w.ShowDialog();
}

Open the second window by tap on the TextBox, then close the second window.
Do 9 touch tap in the blank area of the MainWindow (not on the TextBox),
at ninth the PreviewMouseDown is launched.
This thing happen also if i do e.Handle = true in the TextBox_PreviewTouchDown method.
I'm trying with Windows 11, .Net Framework 4.8.1, VS2022.
